# Drupal hook_form_alter Not redirecting

Tags: drupal, redirect, submit

I am using hook form_alter and setting the $form['#redirect'] = 'dir1/dir2/mypage'. But the form refuses to go there.

Form seems to work otherwise, but keeps sending back to the original form instead of the redirect.

The form I am altering is from the root user module.

```
mymodule_form_alter(     ){

        ... code...

 $form['account']['pass'] = array(
 '#type' => 'password_confirm', 
 '#size' => 25, '#description' => t(''), 
 '#required' => TRUE
 );

 unset($form['Birthdate']['profile_birthdate']);
 unset($form['Birthdate']);
 unset($form['#action']);

 $form['#validate'] = array('_mymodule_school_registration_validate');
 $form['#submit'] = array( '_mymodule_school_registration_submit');
 $form['#redirect']= "dir1/dir2/mypage";

}
```

Please help trying to meet an overdue dead line!!  : (

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter/6) implementation is not correct:

- Without parameters, you're aren't modifying anything, so none of your changes get registered,
- `$form['#submit']` and `$form['#validate']` are already arrays with content, so you should not be resetting them with `array()`,
- unsetting `$form['#action']` causes the form to do nothing when submitted,
- setting `$form['#redirect']` in `hook_form_alter()` will get overridden by other handlers, and
- your `hook_form_alter()` implementation would affect (and break) every form.

More info: [Forms API Reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6)

Instead, try the following:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id === 'form_id_goes_here') {
    // Code here

    $form['account']['pass'] = array(
      '#type' => 'password_confirm', 
      '#size' => 25, 
      '#description' => t(''), 
      '#required' => TRUE
    );

    unset($form['Birthdate']['profile_birthdate']);
    unset($form['Birthdate']);

    $form['#validate'][] = '_mymodule_school_registration_validate';
    $form['#submit'][] = '_mymodule_school_registration_submit';
  }
}

function _mymodule_school_registration_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Code here

  $form_state['redirect'] = 'dir1/dir2/mypage';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$form_state['redirect'] = "dir1/dir2/mypage";
```

Comment: Thanks,
But i tried that.
I also tried:

    <code>  unset( $form_state['storage'] ); </code>

as per pg 250 of Pro Drupal Development by John VanDyk

Answer (score -1):

If you've only got one handler for your submit you could easily redirect with

`function _mymodule_school_registration_submit(..args...) {

...

drupal_goto('somewhere');

}`

I think the functionality is the same.

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_goto/6

I tend to avoid redirects so once you have met your deadline I would refactor your code. You can usually get away with out redirecting.

Comment: Never use `drupal_goto` in a submit handler. Your module will not know what else implements a submit handler, and the point of the handler/hook system is to accommodate other implementations gracefully.

Comment: yes, agreed, Mark. I did resolve this issue finally with variable_set/get and some logic in the validation function. Thanks a lot for the helpful comments.